# Setting up Microsoft Edge with Protractor (JS), Cucumber JS and Gulp - (no Java, no C#)

Tags: selenium, gulp, protractor, microsoft-edge, angularjs-e2e

Does anyone know how to setup the Microsoft Edge browser with Protractor?

I'm using Protractor (Javascript) and Gulp; NOT Java or C#.

Here's my Protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'cucumber',
    seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],
    multiCapabilities: {
       'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge', 
        javascriptEnabled=true,
       //'platform': 'windows',
       // 'version': '11'
    }
    , 
 {
  'browserName': 'chrome', 
  loggingPrefs: {
    driver: 'DEBUG',
    server: 'INFO',
    browser: 'ALL'
  }
}],

}
```

***1. I specify the browser name which is 'MicrosoftEdge' then***
***2. I thought I would point to the EdgeDriver.exe just like I did and it worked for the IE browser.***

What else am I missing, this successfully opens up the Edge browser but fails to navigate to a URL with error

```
var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Has anyone successfully set up Microsoft Edge with Protractor/CucumberJS?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem as you outlined,I noticed you and I are running the same build of Windows 10,

I have managed to find a solution to my problem if you see the small print around the download link on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/mt188085(v=vs.85).aspx

You'll notice there are **three** driver versions try install the following one:

---

[Windows 10 Fall 2015 Update, install Microsoft WebDriver Fall 2015 Update.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=716879)

From the install directory take the 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' and replace your current one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for is the Browser Fingerprint.

While not complete (including MS-Edge), it should point you in the correct direction..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint#External_links

Especially - http://www.darkwavetech.com/fingerprint/fingerprint_code.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give an answer Leptonator; but this is not quite what I am looking for; the links talk about uniquely identifying remote devices or browser through the means of collecting certain information via client-side scripting languages.

Comment: What I am looking for is simply the browser name for my e2e tests; I have updated my config above. For both Chrome and Internet Explorer, I included the browser name in config above; but I have no idea what it should be for Microsoft Edge; I tried a few names like 'Edge', 'Microsoft Edge', 'microsoft edge', 'microsoft-edge', 'MS-Edge' - but in vain, any idea what that browsername should be?

Comment: OK..  Try this..  I just went to: http://browserspy.dk/ and shows just Edge, but includes a bunch of information about Safari (which I don't have installed on my Windows 10 box)..

Comment: Thanks Leptonator; it turns out what I had was right i.e browser name should be MicrosoftEdge. I just forgot to change the system protperty from '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver' to '-Dwebdriver.edge.driver', note the '.edge.driver' instead of '.ie.driver' in there. That being said, I can now successfully launch the Microsoft Edge browser from Protractor but it still doesn't run my e2e tests. It gives me this error: UnknownError: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information). I know that's not much info so I don't expect much of an answer to this issue; thanks again anyways

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following to get Mircosoft Edge to launch from Protractor. 
Here's where I got the driver for Microsoft Edge (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212); you can ***install the .msi file and it'll give you a .exe*** which you can drop in to a location of your choice:

Here's my config file for Microsoft Edge:

```
 exports.config = {
  framework: 'cucumber',
  //Microsoft Edge
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],
  capabilities: {
   'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge',
   'platform': 'windows',
   // 'version': '11'
   },
}
```

Please note if you wanted to just get IE11 then you would use this instead and make sure to point it to wherever you downloaded the ieDriver (http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) to your local machine:

`seleniumArgs: ['webdriver.ie.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe'],`

And don't forget to change the browser name to `'browserName': 'internet explorer',`

This is just a step closer to getting ***Protractor(Javascript and Gulp, please NO Java or C#)*** to work with Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 OS, this launches the Microsoft Edge browser; however I am still running into issues such as:

```
var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: null (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6.95 seconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'DEV-6', ip: '10.10.50.25', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
    at new bot.Error
```

This is a work in progress so I'll update this post as I get more meaningful results; if anyone knows of how to avoid this error to successfully automate Microsoft Edge with Protractor please suggest it here.

And please note ***I am NOT using the Java or C# bindings*** which seem to be very popular on Google results; instead I am using ***Protractor with Javascript and gulp*** for my e2e tests. Any help much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to start a protractor test with edge, here is the relevant part of my protractor.conf :

```
  seleniumArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=node_modules/protractor/selenium/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe'],
  baseUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:4321/index_protractor.html',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'MicrosoftEdge'
  },
```

So it's a mix between all you can read on the Internet (note that the case is important with **M**icrosoft**E**dge).

On the upside, Edge is started and I see the url changing, etc

On the downside, every test I tried failed with this error :

```
Message:
Failed: Error while running testForAngular: not implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 3 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'PORTABLE-SL3', ip: '192.168.43.171', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, browserVersion=20.10240.16384.0, platformVersion=10, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows, platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 732EDD82-B245-4020-8B0E-3FBE0428AAB6
```

So I guess the driver is not ready for Angular

EDIT:

Confirmed, adding this line before my browser.get fixed my error

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
```

I had to handle the wait for Angular manually though. Please note also that by.repeater was not working

Comment: Thanks seblucas but still not working for me. Also, it seems that you only use that browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; for non angular sites (Mine is an ANGULAR site) and lastly, in cases where you do not want to wait for a promise to resolve. Maybe your site is not an angular site? In any event, I should at least be able to do browser.get(URL) which I can't at the moment.  And I did have the case right on "MicrosoftEdge"

Comment: My site is also an Angular one. I just tested to make sure (Edge is removed from the browsers I test against). Did you install the right version of Edge Webdriver (there's a difference between W10 build 10240 and W10 Fall 2015 Update). I personally used W10 build 10240's Webdriver.

Comment: another difference is I'm using Webdriver 2.48.2

Comment: Sorry to pester you Seblucas but this is the link I use to get the driver: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212  Is there another link?

Comment: Actually I just checked and i'm using Windows 10 Pro which is probably NOT supported. Here's the list of supported Operating System: 
Windows 10 , Windows 10 Tech Preview and Windows 10 Build 10240 AND mine is Windows 10 Pro; that's most likely the reason mine is not working; I'll test it on a different VM and if it works I'll let you know later

Comment: I'm using winver to check my Windows 10 version. About the version difference I was talking about this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/mt188085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (in french sorry)

Comment: Oh I did not know of the winver tool; I see: Windows 10, Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.63) - But later it says the Windows 10 Pro operating system and its user intefacea re protected by trademark; Looks like Windows 10 Pro and just Windows 10 are the same thing - So Edge should work; I'll have to dive a little deeper to investigate what's going on, Merci beaucoup a vous :)